# Is there a way to return documents that match conditions specified in a JavaScript function via forEach()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Is it possible to fetch documents that match the conditions inside a JS function, something like:

```
db.getCollection("persons").find({"dob.age":{$eq:70} } ).forEach(function(doc) { 
 if(doc.registered.age == doc.dob.age*2){ //or some other complicated conditions
    return doc;
   }
});
```

The above code doesn't work but if it did I would expect it to return all documents where `registered.age` is two times their `dob.age`

it possible?

EDIT:

As per advice in the comments I have tried it with map() and it sort of works

**persons collection:**

```
{ "_id" : 1, "test1" : 95, "test2" : 92, "test3" : 90, "modified" : ISODate("2020-01-04T18:30:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "test1" : 98, "test2" : 100, "test3" : 102, "modified" : ISODate("2020-01-04T18:30:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 3, "test1" : 95, "test2" : 110, "modified" : ISODate("2020-01-03T18:30:00Z") }
```

**Result:**

```
[
    undefined,
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "test1" : 98,
        "test2" : 100,
        "test3" : 102,
        "modified" : ISODate("2020-01-04T18:30:00Z")
    },
    undefined
]
```

What I did not understand is why there are two undefined?

Also does this approach make use of indexing?

Comment: Use `filter()` instead of `forEach()` and win.

Comment: Neither map nor filter seem to be working for me :/

Comment: Since this is mongo, you may have to do `map(it => it).filter(....)`, because the lookup returns a cursor.

Comment: Also, why don't you just do `db.getCollection('persons').find({ "dob.age': 70, 'dob.registered.age': 140})` ?

Comment: @Taplar plz see my edit

Comment: filter, not map.  See my (now) second comment to this post

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Short answer:

```
db.getCollection("persons").find({"dob.age":{$eq:70} } ).filter(function(doc) { 
 return (doc.registered.age == doc.dob.age*2) //or some other complicated conditions
});
```

`Array.forEach()` simply executes a function once for every element of the array. It doesn't return anything and, by itself, it doesn't do anything to modify or filter the array.

`Array.map()` also executes a function once for every element of the array, but each time it calls the function, it uses the function's return value to build a new array with the same number of elements as the input array.

`Array.filter()` is similar: it executes a function once for every element of the array, and it builds a new array, but it expects the function to return either `true` or `false`. If the function returns `true`, then it includes that element from the input array in the new array that it's building. If the function returns `false`, then it does NOT include that element from the input array in the new array that it's building.

The reason you are getting `undefined` is you are using `Array.map()`, which is building a new array with the exact same number of elements as the input array. Your function is written so that it returns `doc` if the condition is true, but if the condition is false, it returns nothing (`undefined`).

`Array.filter()` is what you want. And you should make your function return either `true` or `false` depending on whether you want that array element to be included in the output.

Side note: My inclination would be to perform the comparison as a part of your database query, but to answer your question of whether or not you can do this locally in JavaScript, yes it can be done.

Comment: is basically with filter I have already fetched all the data and then I am filtering it out locally? I was hoping mongo could accept javascript function to search for document in the db.

Comment: Yes you are correct, your question mentioned filtering a local javascript array using forEach, which would happen locally AFTER the results were returned from the db driver.  If you want to perform arbitrary comparison logic server side as a part of the query, then you'll have to use different combinations of the operators that mongodb provides, depending on what your conditions are. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/